# Mailgun.js throws unauthorized 401 MailgunAPIError

Tags: next.js13, mailgun, mailgun-api

I'm trying to implement sending newsletter emails for my blog. I follow this article [Guide](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-add-an-email-newsletter-to-your-next-js-and-storyblok-powered-blog) except I use Sanity instead of Storyblok.

I managed to verify my domain, trigger Sanity webhook to make POST request, add subscribers' emails to Mailing list but somehow encounter 401 error while trying to send newsletter.

What I have tried:

- Switching url parameter from default to '[https://api.eu.mailgun.net](https://api.eu.mailgun.net/)'
- Switching from my domain to Mailgun sandbox domain.
- Switching between Domain Sending API key and Mailgun API key
- Adding ngrok Web Interface to Mailgun's IP Access Management
- Adding 'key' to key parameter e.g: key: `key-${process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY}`
- Adding prefix NEXT_PUBLIC to enviroment variables e.g: NEXT_PUBLIC_MAILGUN_API_KEY
- Install dotenv package

What I think could cause the error: my domain is registered in Vietnam with ending .vn